# Cannot import xlwings on PyCharm and eror while trying to install it

Tags: python, pycharm, python-import, xlwings

I'm truing to import xlwings on PyCharm but I get an Eror:

```
C:\Python\Analize_Data\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Python/Analize_Data/the_class.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/Analize_Data/the_class.py", line 3, in <module>
    import xlwings as xw
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'xlwings'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

so I tried instaling it from the File->Settings->Project Interpreter but I get another eror:

```
Collecting xlwings
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/63/20/b131eb5c3f35c721ba473e824b569f995994c32f1b2829a14d0b24aeb78e/xlwings-0.20.7.tar.gz
Collecting comtypes (from xlwings)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/fb/b8/f8aa21774acb4535e32f6a89055876ca497ff806f9b1b1912b469284a61e/comtypes-1.1.7.zip
Collecting pywin32>=224 (from xlwings)

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32>=224 (from xlwings) (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pywin32>=224 (from xlwings)
```

Installing it on pip makes no difference.
Tried installing pywin32. also does not work:

```
Collecting pywin32

  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pywin32 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pywin32
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

What's your python version? Python 2 or 3?
Try to install `pip install pypiwin32` first !

Comment: Python 3.8.     And I also did that. doesn't seem to help any